# ng build --prod = Cannot set property '_autoActivated' of undefined

Tags: angular, gsap

I'm trying to deploy my Angular App but after running `ng build --prod --base-href .` I get the following error in Chrome

```
main.afc84290417a517dd6c3.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property _autoActivated' of undefined
    at Object.zUnb (main.afc84290417a517dd6c3.js:1)
    at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
    at Object.5 (main.afc84290417a517dd6c3.js:1)
    at p (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
    at n (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
    at Array.e [as push] (runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1)
    at main.afc84290417a517dd6c3.js:1
```

ng -v outputs

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

I'm not really sure how to go aout debugging this? Running `ng serve` the app runs fine.

Searching the project the only reference to `_autoActivated` is in TweenMax.js

```
export const TweenMax = TweenMaxBase;
TweenMax._autoActivated = [TimelineLite, TimelineMax, CSSPlugin, AttrPlugin, BezierPlugin, RoundPropsPlugin, DirectionalRotationPlugin, Back, Elastic, Bounce, RoughEase, SlowMo, SteppedEase, Circ, Expo, Sine, ExpoScaleEase];
```

App dependencies -

```
 "@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
    "@types/three": "^0.92.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "gsap": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "three": "^0.87.1",
    "three-effectcomposer-es6": "0.0.4",
    "three-screen-quad": "^0.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Comment: you don't happen to use gsap? Please share your other dependencies with us.

Comment: Yes I am!? Questions updated

Comment: If you build with the --prod option it happens to cause some problems. Do the same problems occur if you just ng build? The AOT Compiler seems to cause problems here. If it is working without --prod see: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler for more information

Comment: yes you are right, just running ng build, it works fine... :/

Comment: ..not really sure what I can do about that ?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. You have to add the following scripts to `angular.json`

```html
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/gsap/umd/TweenMax.js",
              "./node_modules/gsap/umd/ScrollToPlugin.js"]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Turning off BuildOptimization is not advisable as it creates very large bundle sizes.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue, it's caused by GSAP in combination with Angular's Build Optimizer.

You can disable this at the cost of some filesize by heading into your `angular.json`.
Set your production build config up like this:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": false, // <-- This ensures compatibility with GSAP
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it works!! do you know that have any issue can follow, hope we can use buildOptimizer in the future

Comment: Turning off buildOptimizer increases the size of the bundles and is inadvisable. See @Yunus answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, switch gsap for another library like popmotions and it works.

This is because TweenMax uses functions like `getBoundingClientRect()` and tries to append div's to the dom to determine some stuff. Which obviously isn't possible in the server.

I still prefer gsap over popmotion (horrible syntax in my opinion) but i've tried numerous things.

• Lazy loading gsap (not ideal).

• Adjusting the gsap library (not ideal)

• Mocking window, document & navigator with a library called domino

All no luck. If anyone finds a solution with gsap i would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Angular 9.0.7. I also had a problem with a production build and received some error messages. It is not necessary to add scripts to the Angular.json file. It is also sufficient to use the normal imports. Therefore please do not import "all".

The following solution had helped me:

Include the following lines of code in the **Main.ts** file:

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { CSSPlugin } from 'gsap/CSSPlugin';

gsap.registerPlugin(CSSPlugin);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

USE `import {TweenMax} from 'gsap/umd/TweenMax';` instead of `import {TweenMax} from 'gsap/TweenMax'`;

Answer (score -1):

Try to change you imports.
From something like:

```
import { TweenLite } from 'gsap'
```

To something like:

```
import { TweenLite } from 'gsap/all'
```

Comment: Importing from /all is a convenience. It shouldn't have an effect on this sort of thing.